# Displaying a graphic when audio is playing

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

Trying to find a way to display a small graphic to indicate when an audio clip is playing. Similar to the way in which an icon appears in the tab in Chrome whenever sound is currently playing, but displayed as a gif or similar on the actual page.

This is a simplified version of how the audio clips are displayed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function playSound(el,soundfile) {
          if (el.mp3) {
              if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
              else el.mp3.pause();
          } else {
              el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
              el.mp3.play();
          }
      }
</script>

<div onclick="playSound(this, '<?php echo htmlentities($filepath, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>');">
```

Lots of links to files on a page displayed in timelines, when the div is clicked they begin to play. We want a graphic to be displayed when any audio clip begins playing, and then to be hidden when the clip comes to an end.

Comment: What audio clip ? Do you have any code ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added some more info and code

Comment: You should add the Javascript / jQuery tagg to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with JavaScript.
You can use jQuery to show / hide your graphic :

Let's say your graphic has the id : #sound_playing

html :

```
<img id="sound_playing" src="sound_playing.png" />
```

JavaScript :

```
$sound_playing = $('#sound_playing');

if (your_sound.paused == false) {
    $sound_playing.show();
    alert('music is playing');
} else if {
    $sound_playing.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html, you will have that somewhere :

```
<img id="playimg" src="url_of_img" />
```

And in your javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function playSound(el,soundfile) {
          if (el.mp3) {
              if(el.mp3.paused){
                   el.mp3.play();
                   document.getElementById("playimg").style.visibility = "visible";
              }
              }else {
                   el.mp3.pause();
                   document.getElementById("playimg").style.visibility = "hidden";
              }
          } else {
              el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
              el.mp3.play();
              document.getElementById("playimg").style.visibility = "visible";
          }
      }
</script>
```

**Live example**  but not exactly with this script as I don't have the script that plays mp3 files : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iqadf